# Can Jarvis marching algorith return UNso0rted results?

Tags: geometry, d, convex-hull

I am trying to compute a complex hull for a very complex point set. See picture:

[image]

The green/teal line to the left contains convex hull points that are neighboring, i.e. come directly after one another. continuing the sequence, the next point should be the cyan/green one in right bottom.

However, if i walk along the array, the next one appears to be the one in top right, in yellow.

Yes, output is in ascii, point cloud is correct (compared with GUI output) .

Snippet:

```
for(int i = 0; i< rd.length; i++) {
if( (*rd)[i].lon < lonMin) {
     lonMin = (*rd)[i].lon;
     leftMostPos = i;
}
}


 int [] hullIdx = new int[0];

 int p = leftMostPos, m = to!int((*rd).length), q;

 do {

    hullIdx ~= [p];

    q = (p + 1) % m;

    for ( int ij = 0; ij < m ; ij ++) {

         auto a = (*rd)[p];
         auto b = (*rd)[ij];
         auto c = (*rd)[q];

         double ornt = (b.lat - a.lat) * ( c.lon - b.lon) - (b.lon - a.lon) * (c.lat - b.lat) ;
         if (ornt < 0) q = ij;


      }
      p = q;

 } while ( p != leftMostPos);
```

Language is D, I am solving for Geographical Lats and Lons. Lons are taken as a coordinates, lats are in x coordinate. The Matrix increases y coordinate by row, towards downward direction. This is also taken into account.

I would like to know how come Jarvis algorithm returns UNsorted output. I would apppreciate all your help with gratefulness.

Comment: Code looks similar to [this implementation](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/convex-hull-set-1-jarviss-algorithm-or-wrapping/). Is argument order in `ornt` correct? Have you checked debug output for for-loop at strange point?

Comment: Yes, argument order is p, i , q 

yes, i checked but i am a bit confused. with a normal nominal 5-gon , 6 gon ... up to 10 gon, it had not created any problems.

Comment: I always found Andrew's algorithm to be a much easier convex hull algorithm to implement, it's also more efficient with large convex hulls.  https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Geometry/Convex_hull/Monotone_chain (seems the D implementation is missing, pehaps add it once you're done?)

Comment: @Nuclearman this i will do